# Скачать файл по sftp с помощью paramiko. Ошибка paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner

Tags: python-3.x, ssh, paramiko

Нужно скачать файл с сервера, но при подключении получаю ошибку:
**paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner**

Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить эту проблему ?

```
import paramiko


def get_file():
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect("", 21, '', '', banner_timeout=300 )


    sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
    sftp.get('/CommonPrice.xml', 'CommonPrice2.xml')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_file()
```

Comment: 21 это обычно порт не для SSH, а для FTP...

Comment: вы правы.. только теперь другая ошибка paramiko.ssh_exception.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed.

Comment: А вы уверены, что вам нужно использовать именно SFTP, а не FTP?

Comment: вы правы снова... нужно использовать FTP

Comment: получается через paramiko я не скачаю файл. Я понял. Спасибо за помощь.